# How to Reference Variables in a Controller for a Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

I wrote a large class within my Controller and I cannot figure out how to allow the variables contained within the controller to be referenced on a Visualforce page. Why can I not just use {!data.variablename}. This is a big nooblet question, I am sorry guys.

```
public class StatController {

    public StatController(ApexPages.standardController Controller) {}

    public void getData() {
        Month_Sales__c calcRecord = [SELECT Id
            FROM Month_Sales__c
            WHERE Account__c =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
            ORDER BY End_Date__c
            LIMIT 1
        ];
        Date lastMonthEndDate = calcRecord.End_Date__c;
        String BusinessTID = calcRecord.BusinessTID;
        String JUPAccountName = calcRecord.Company_Name__c;
        String ProductCode = calcRecord.Code__c;
        Decimal ytdSpendSum;
        Decimal pytdSpendSum;
        Decimal ytdCreditLimitSum;
        Decimal pytdCreditLimitSum;
        Decimal ytdAvgPerUtil;
        Decimal pytdAvgPerUtil;
        Date stripDate = lastMonthEndDate.addMonths(-12);
        Integer month = stripDate.Month();
        Integer year = stripDate.Year();
        Integer day = date.daysInMonth(year, month);
        date.isLeapYear(year);
        Date pytdCalcDate = date.newInstance(year, month, day);

        if (date.isLeapYear(year) && month == 2) {
            pytdCalcDate.addDays(1);

        }
        for (Month_Sales__c cspend: [SELECT Id
                FROM Month_Sales__c
                WHERE Account__c =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
            ]) {
            if (cspend.End_Date__c < pytdCalcDate) 
            {
                pytdSpendSum += cspend.Month_Sales__c;
                pytdCreditLimitSum += cspend.Credit_Limit__c;
            } else {
                ytdSpendSum += cspend.Month_Sales__c;
                ytdCreditLimitSum += cspend.Credit_Limit__c;
            }
        }
        ytdAvgPerUtil = (ytdSpendSum / ytdCreditLimitSum) * 100;
        pytdAvgPerUtil = (pytdSpendSum / pytdCreditLimitSum) * 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which field you need to reference and where is your VF page code for that?

Comment: @highfive I do not need to reference a field. I want to reference the variables from my getData(). The data I want is from an unrelated object and is calculated as needed in the controller.

Comment: To access the variable you need to define the variable in getter method. Ex..String variablename {get; set;}. Now you can reference independently the variable on VF page. {!variablename}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your variables to be local to the method which means their values (references) will be discarded when the method finishes. Instead you need the declarations to be [Apex properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm), which as that link illustrates can be done in several ways.

A key point about using Apex properties is to ensure that the values have been set before they are referenced by the Visualforce. If the properties are independent, using lazy loading works well:

```
public String someProperty {
    get {
        if (someProperty == null) {
            someProperty = ...;
        }
        return someProperty;
    }
    set;
}
```

But if there are many inter-related properties as you have, initializing them from the controller constructor makes sense.

(There are also more awkward cases where they can only be initialized when a value is passed back to the controller from the page; extra care is needed over execution order in those cases.)

Comment: I have added a public Date lastMonthEndDate{get;set;}. I am referencing this as <apex:outputText label="TEST: " value="{!lastMonthEndDate}"/>. It does not seem to put anything out. I am guessing an order of execution.

Comment: @Mercury86 Yes you need to execute some code that sets the value. A reference is null until you set it to something. You can do that in the controller constructor e.g. call `getData` from the constructor (if getData assigns that value).

Comment: Is there anyway I could pick your brain?, I think what I have written so far is no good and has to be discarded. I cannot figure out how to call getData from the constructor. I just want to get the variables out my dang public void getData method so I can display them as an output on a visualforce page.

Comment: @Mercury86 Its `public StatController(ApexPages.standardController Controller) { getData(); }`.

Comment: Thanks Keith C, made some progress, Now its "Content cannot be displayed: Attempt to de-reference a null object". I figure it is something with my :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') in the SOQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the variable outside the method of `getData()`

```
public class StatController {

public Date lastMonthEndDate{get;set;}
public String BusinessTID{get;set;}
public String JUPAccountName{get;set;}
public String ProductCode{get;set;}

public StatController(ApexPages.standardController Controller){
    getData();
}

public void getData(){

Month_Sales__c calcRecord =[SELECT Id
                         FROM Month_Sales__c
                         WHERE Account__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
                         ORDER BY End_Date__c 
                         LIMIT 1];

lastMonthEndDate = calcRecord.End_Date__c;
BusinessTID = calcRecord.BusinessTID;
JUPAccountName = calcRecord.Company_Name__c;
ProductCode = calcRecord.Code__c;

}
```

Comment: Just declaring them outside the method won't work. They need to be declared as *properties* (which your code does, but you didn't mention)

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy I gave your solution a shot, nothing is returned. I am trying to get data from the controller and display it on a visualforce page. Could you give me a hint? I figure since getData is void nothing is returned.

Comment: Ofcourse, you should call the getData in the constructor.  OR you can call the getData in your "action" property in <apex:page /> too